# Extjs 4 - How to up to parent component in initComponent function

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I define a gridpanel like

```
    Ext.define('Example', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',   
        alias: 'myGrid',
        store:Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: [
                {name: 'name'}
            ]
        }),
        initComponent: function() {
             alert(this.up('window').title); //but error like this.up(...) is undefined
             this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    ...
```

And I create a window have a item above

```
   items: {  
        xtype: 'myGrid'
    }
```

I want to get some thing in parent componet. How to up to `parent component` in initComponent function. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    initComponent: function() {
         var me = this;

         this.callParent(arguments);
         me.on('render', function() {
             alert(me.up('window').title);
         });
    }
```

Comment: that's good but that only working inside `render function` if I init a variable inside `render function` and alert it outside that's not working?

Comment: @LookAtMeNow Yes. "up()" will working after adding a component to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The component must first be instantiated before it is added to the container. You can override the `onAdded` template method, which will get called when the component is added to a container:

```
Ext.define('Foo',
    extend: 'Ext.Component',

    onAdded: function(ct) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        console.log('Added to', ct);
    }
});
```

Comment: Not really sure how it's difficult, but ok.